# Automatically resolve git conflicts in binary files with a script

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

We have a lot of branches on a lot of repositories, and all of them have binary files (I know it's bad - But we have to have them in). That means that almost every merge or sync is conflicted at those files.

We've created a script, which compiles the project and creates those files, and now we just run it when conflicts occur ,it overrides the conflicts files with correct ones, and we mark those files as resolved.

This is great and time-saving, but now I want to know if there is a way to make git do it himself. Meaning, instead of '--ours' or '--theirs', choosing a more complex logic to resolve specific conflicted files (running a script that overrides them)

Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: If you are getting frequent merge conflicts due to *autogenerated content* then you should give this workflow some serious rethinking (specifically, *don't* commit autogenerated content).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your script into a custom merge driver and mark your binary files for being merged with that driver. Read the [gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) for more details; following is a slightly edited relevant excerpt from it:

> **Performing a three-way merge**
>
> `merge` The attribute merge affects how three versions of a file are
>   merged when a file-level merge is necessary during `git merge`, and
>   other commands such as `git revert` and `git cherry-pick`.
>
> When this attribute is set to a string, 3-way merge is performed using
>   the specified custom merge driver. The built-in 3-way merge driver can
>   be explicitly specified by asking for "text" driver; the built-in
>   "take the current branch" driver can be requested with "binary".
>
> **Defining a custom merge driver**
>
> The definition of a merge driver is done in the `.git/config` file,
>   not in the `gitattributes` file.
>
> To define a custom merge driver filfre, add a section to your
>   `$GIT_DIR/config` file (or `$HOME/.gitconfig` file) like this:
>
> ```
> [merge "filfre"]
>   name = feel-free merge driver
>   driver = filfre %O %A %B %L %P
>   recursive = binary
> ```
>
> The `merge.*.name` variable gives the driver a human-readable name.
>
> The `merge.*.driver` variable’s value is used to construct a command
>   to run to merge ancestor’s version (`%O`), current version (`%A`) and
>   the other branches' version (`%B`). These three tokens are replaced
>   with the names of temporary files that hold the contents of these
>   versions when the command line is built. Additionally, `%L` will be
>   replaced with the conflict marker size (see the `conflict-marker-size`
>   attribute).
>
> The merge driver is expected to leave the result of the merge in the
>   file named with `%A` by overwriting it, and exit with zero status if
>   it managed to merge them cleanly, or non-zero if there were conflicts.

So, assuming that your merge driver is called `recompile_merge` and you want it to be applied to *.o files, you will need the following entry in your `gitattributes` file:

```
 *.o merge=recompile_merge
```

One possible problem is making sure that the corresponding source files are merged *before* the binary files that must be merged in your custom way.